# Can I dynamically restrict build slaves a job can run on based on the current build queue?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Sorry if this question, or something similar has already been asked, but I couldn't find anything. Perhaps I was searching for the wrong thing, which given the bad name of this question could easily be the case.

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to restrict jobs, but not in an absolute way which is the only way I know how. I'll give an example of what I mean:

Lets say we have jobs A B and C (fast builds) and jobs X Y and Z (slow builds) and only 3 build slaves.

If Job A is running on slave 1 and then X Y Z are ordered to build X and Y take salves 2 and 3 and Z goes into the build queue. So far this is the way Jenkins always works.

Lets say job A will finish first since in my case jobs X Y and Z are much larger jobs.

If A finishes and there is nothing in the queue but Z then Z should start to run on slave 1. BUT what I would *really* like is that if B or C got put in the build queue **AFTER** Z I would want them to be run on slave 1 before Z does.

Essentially I want slave 1 to have an affinity for jobs A B C (Well actually its an affinity for things that aren't X Y or Z)

The reason I want to know this is I am hoping to split jobs X Y and Z into many smaller jobs so they don't tie up build slaves for as long. Of course this wouldn't matter if it was just a bunch of jobs that would run in succession and take just as long (longer even). This would allow other jobs to always have somewhere to build but would still let jobs X Y Z take advantage of all slaves as long as nothing else was building. And if something else was building it would only have to wait for a fraction of XYorZ to finish on that semi-reserved node before they leapfrogged over XYZ in the queue for that slave.

Thanks